# package io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences does not exist after upgrading flutter shared_preferences to version 2.2.2

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences

**show this error after run "flutter upgrade"**

this problem hide when stop sharedPreferences from pubspec.yaml .

i try change dart-sdk version from pubspec.yaml but nothinge changed .

[this image show version of shared_Preferences that used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qm44Y.png)

This is the error :

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
D:\windows\flutter_project\salfa_game\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java:34: error: package io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences does not exist
      flutterEngine.getPlugins().add(new io.flutter.plugins.sharedpreferences.SharedPreferencesPlugin());
                                                                         ^
```

1 error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

I expect this error from dart-sdk last version dev chanall:3.4.0-64.0.dev 
this is dart sdk version : 3.4.0-64.0.dev,
```

Comment: try to clean your project by entering the command flutter clean and type flutter pub get on terminal

Comment: Can you add the 'flutter doctor -v' output ?

Answer (score 0):

best solve for this problem after very tried ,

delete the flutter sdk from C:\src
and download again :https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows/mobile?tab=download ....
after finish all thing work .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I am getting this error almost every package I added lately, this can be fixed by

> restarting your computer

`But this is not a solid solution`